# Баг в коде. c++. ifstream

Tags: c++

Почему этот код падает с Segmentation fault?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void func(std::ifstream &f, std::string &key_len_str) {
    char *c;
    f.read(c, 1);
    key_len_str += (std::string) c;
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream f("f.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
    std::string s = "";
    func(f, s);
    func(f, s);
    func(f, s);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую вам полностью переписать код.
Так как вы получаете только 1 символ, было бы логичнее использовать функцию `get`.
Вы передаёте строку `key_len_str` с типом `string`, который является контейнером, состоящим из элементов char, в него можно положить объект типа `char` с помощью метода `push_back`.
Я исправил ваш код с учётом рекомендаций:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void func(std::ifstream &f, std::string &key_len_str) {
    char c;
    f.get(c);
    key_len_str.push_back(c);
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream f("f.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
    std::string s = "";
    func(f, s);
    func(f, s);
    func(f, s);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

бага здесь

```
char *c;
f.read(c, 1);
```

Вы создаете указатель на переменную типа char, но память не выделяете. Как исправить.

Хороший вариант

```
char c;
f.read(&c, 1);
```

Похуже, сильно похуже (вариант не рекомендуется к употреблению в реальных программах, кроме случая, если это нужно для обезумевшего преподавателя).

```
char * c = new char;
f.read(&c,1);
delete c;
```

Comment: Я знаю, что это плохой пример. И написал об этом. Но вопрошающий должен знать, как выделить память.

Comment: Предлагаю версию с `new` переделать на массив, а `1` оформить в виде именованной константы, тогда будет более общий случай использования `istream.read`.

Comment: я понимаю ваше негодование. И в реальном коде я даже не могу представить, почему бы я такое напишу. Но в этом случае я минимально исправлял код автора вопроса, что бы он работал корректно.